# Conditionally rendering HTML elements with querySelector based on boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I'm working on a Chrome extension so my approach is different to how I'd usually go about this.

I have the below HTML, which includes elements that may or may not be displayed depending on a boolean value in the javascript file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mvp.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <header>
            <h1 style="width: 400px">Title</h1>
            <p style="font-size: 1rem;">Messages to non paying users</p>
            <button class="join-btn">Join now!</button>
            <a style="cursor: pointer; margin-top: 4px;">Message for paying users</a>
        </header>
        <script src="ExtPay.js"></script>
        <script defer src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS file is like so:

```
const extpay = ExtPay('my-ext-ID');

document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', extpay.openPaymentPage);

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', extpay.openPaymentPage);

extpay
  .getUser()
  .then((user) => {
    if (user.paid) {
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Message to paying users';
      document.querySelector('button').remove();
    } else {
      document.querySelector('a').remove();
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML =
      "Error fetching data :( Check that your ExtensionPay id is correct and you're connected to the internet";
  });
```

So what this does is that if the `user` is a paying customer, then the contents of the `<p>` changes and the "Join now" button is removed, and if they are not a paying customer, the `<a>` is removed.

The problem I have with this approach is that for a short amount of time (<1sec) - the the HTML renders in its entirity (including both elements for paying & non-paying users) before the JS kicks in and updates accordingly. How can I update this so that this doesn't happen? I have tried adding `defer` to the script calls but to no avail.

Comment: Don’t render join now by default?  Leave that space empty until the request completes, and in the else of the then put the join now button in.

Answer (score -1):

You can try another approach, You can create empty div with id and then based on the conditions you can create those p and button elements and append it to that div. Like for example:

```
<header>

<h1 style="width: 400px">Title</h1>
<div id="header"></div>
<a style="cursor: pointer; margin-top: 4px;">Message for paying users</a>

</header>

<script>

const para = document.createElement("p");
const node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);
//append it to (document.getElementById('header'))
if (!user.paid) {
var a = document.createElement("button");
a.innerText = "Join now!";
//append it to (document.getElementById('header'))
}
</script>
```